# How do I show GitBook title?

Tags: html, css, gitbook

In GitBook, the title shows up while mousing over them by default.

[image: GitBook title hover]

I wanna show up the title. I inspect the elements,

```html
<div class="book-header" role="navigation">
    <!-- Title -->
    <h1>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>
        <a href=".." >Preface</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

and related CSS is,

```
.book-header h1 a, .book-header h1 a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I add the following CSS,

```css
.book-header h1 a {
    display: block !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

---

Update:

I follow the answer from @ED Wu, and add the following code to CSS,

```css
.book-header h1 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The title does show up. However, the left sidebar doesn't show up while I click on `三` (no action) after adding `opacity:1`. An example is [here](https://dianyao.co/python).

[image]

Comment: Inspect the element via Developer Tools in browser. Is your newly added CSS being overridden by other CSS declarations?

Comment: @Raptor, I appended `!important` to `display:block`.

Comment: @Raptor here is an example using GitBook, [http://dianyao.co/python/](http://dianyao.co/python/).

Comment: 1. Your CSS does not appear in the site; 2. the element's opacity is 0. Therefore, even if you are using `display: block`, it's still invisible.

Comment: Please share more details. What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because .book-header h1 opacity is 0.

Try add this to your css.

```
.book-header h1 {
   opacity:1!important;
}
```

Comment: even without the `!important`, this works fine for OP. For the best practice of CSS, you should add a semi-colon after each CSS property entry.

Comment: `opacity:1` works. However, `btn pull-left js-toolbar-action` and `dropdown pull-left font-settings js-toolbar-action` doesn't work. Pls give me some hints. An example is [here](https://dianyao.co/python/).

Comment: @SparkAndShine Do you want to set  "js-toolbar-action" button's  color more deeper such as on hover?

Comment: @EDWu, the left sidebar doesn't show up while I click on `三`  with your solution `opacity:1`.

Comment: @SparkAndShine I think opacity set 1 would not impact your sidebar.

Comment: @EDWu, unfortunately, it did.

Comment: @SparkAndShine Update your code to gitbook .

Answer (score 0):

Try this! More about `color: inherit` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp). You can use other property like `z-index`, `opacity` and `position` if it doesn't work too. Thanks :)

```css
.book-header h1 a, .book-header h1 a:hover {
    display: block !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-header" role="navigation">
    <!-- Title -->
    <h1>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>
        <a href=".." >Preface</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't abuse using `!important`